# Insertion of blank columns at repetitive positions in a large data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For example,

```
dataX = data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(2:6),c=c(3:7),d=c(4:8),e=c(5:9),f=c(6:10))
```

How do I insert a blank column after every 2 columns?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you rely on column order for some reason?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes sir. I have a dataframe with repetitive 1094 columns. I need to work on it for a research paper but my work would become extremely easy if I have blank columns at specific points which are repetitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use use `split` to split the dataset at unique positions into a `list` of `data.frame`, loop through the `list`, `cbind` with `NA` and `cbind` the elements together

```
res <- do.call(cbind, setNames(lapply(split.default(dataX, (seq_len(ncol(dataX))-1)%/%2), 
                 function(x) cbind(x, NewCol = NA)), NULL))
res
#  a b NewCol c d NewCol e  f NewCol
#1 1 2     NA 3 4     NA 5  6     NA
#2 2 3     NA 4 5     NA 6  7     NA
#3 3 4     NA 5 6     NA 7  8     NA
#4 4 5     NA 6 7     NA 8  9     NA
#5 5 6     NA 7 8     NA 9 10     NA

names(res) <- make.unique(names(res))
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Just to improve my knowledge and learn, can you please explain in 2 lines how this works? It would be quite helpful.

Comment: @AKR  Thanks, If you notice the `split.default(dataX, (seq_len(ncol(dataX))-1)%/%2)`, it splits the data.frame into a `list` of 2 column data.frame each.  Then, we loop through the `list` and append a new NA column with `cbind` Finally, all the `list` elements are converted to a single data frame with `do.call(cbind`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar method that uses a trick with matrices and integer selection of columns. The original data.frame gets an NA column with `cbind`. The columns of this new object are then referenced with every two columns and then the final NA column using a matrix to fill in the final column with `rbind`.

```
cbind(dataX, NewCol=NA)[c(rbind(matrix(seq_along(dataX), 2), ncol(dataX)+1))]
  a b NewCol c d NewCol.1 e  f NewCol.2
1 1 2     NA 3 4       NA 5  6       NA
2 2 3     NA 4 5       NA 6  7       NA
3 3 4     NA 5 6       NA 7  8       NA
4 4 5     NA 6 7       NA 8  9       NA
5 5 6     NA 7 8       NA 9 10       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us construct a empty data frame with the same number of rows as dataX

```
empty_df <- data.frame(x1=rep(NA,nrow(df)),x2=rep(NA,nrow(df)),x3=rep(NA,nrow(df)))
dataX<-cbind(dataX,empty_df)
dataX<-dataX[c("a","b","x1","c","d","x2","e","f","x3")]
```

resulting in:

```
   a b x1 c d x2 e  f x3
 1 1 2 NA 3 4 NA 5  6 NA
 2 2 3 NA 4 5 NA 6  7 NA
 3 3 4 NA 5 6 NA 7  8 NA
 4 4 5 NA 6 7 NA 8  9 NA
 5 5 6 NA 7 8 NA 9 10 NA
```